# Why doesn't ThemeData's fontFamily apply to all text like AppBar, Tab, etc

Tags: flutter, text, themes, textstyle, themedata

I finally found out.

I set the `fontFamily` as follows.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetMaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
    ),
    ...,
  );
}
```

And I wanted to change the `textStyle` of the `AppBar` as well, so I set it as follows.

```dart
child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text(
      'Awesome Title'
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  ...,
),
```

wow

`AppBar`'s `fontFamily` had to be set separately.

```dart
style: TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily', // <- this must go in
  ...,
),
```

Why is this?

Looking for it, is the `TabBar` like that too?
I set the `labelStyle` because I wanted to make the `Tab`'s font fancy, but the `fontFamily` was missing.

```dart
child: TabBar(
  labelStyles: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily', // <- this must go in
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  ...,
),
```

But what? Just `Text` widget comes out with the `fontFamily` set in `ThemeData` even if there is no `fontFamily`.

```dart
Text(
  'Applied fontFamily',
  style(
    // here is no fontFamily
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

So it was only now that I found out.

I am very confused right now.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hint as to why this is.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the hint you need:

```
return GetMaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      // Setting fontFamily for the bodyText1 text style, that is used by default for the Text widget.
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
      ),

      // Setting fontFamily for the bodyText1 text style, that is used by default for the AppBar title and also for TabBar label if you use DefaultTabController.
      headline6: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
      ),

      //Setting fontFamily for the bodyText1 text style, that is used by default for the TabBar label.
      subtitle1: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
      ),
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      // Setting fontFamily for the AppBar title text style.
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline6: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      // Setting fontFamily for the TabBar label text style.
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'YourAwesomeFontFamily',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

happy coding...

Comment: Text Widget's fontFamily is applied without bodyText1's TextStyle. AppBar, TabBar TextStyle is not applied despite of setting headline6, subtitle1. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: please check the updated one and let me know if your problem solved

Comment: Yes, it changed fontFamily of AppBar, TabBar, but it couldn't changed the fontFamily of AppBar and TabBar which have custom textStyle without fontFamily

Comment: The problem is not that I cant' change fontFamily of appbar and tabbar, but the problem is that why I have to apply fontFamily again. When I was already set fontFamily of ThemeData.

Comment: this is because if you speciffy a TextStyle for a widget, and any TextStyle properties that are not speciffied will default to the values in the ThemeData, but any TextStyle properties that are specified will override the values in the ThemeData.anything else???

Comment: My question is that why AppBar and TabBar's fontFamily are removed when custom textStyle (which has not fontFamily) is applied. But Text widget's fontFamily is not removed when custom textStyle (which has not fontFamily) is applied.

Comment: I used the word 'removed' as when ThemeData's fontFamily is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.

`Text` widget's `TextStyle` has `inherit` property.

If `inherit` is `false`, it'll override `TextStyle`, but default value is `true`.

**text.dart**

```dart
/// If non-null, the style to use for this text.
///
/// If the style's "inherit" property is true, the style will be merged with
/// the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle]. Otherwise, the style will
/// replace the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle].
final TextStyle? style;
```

But `AppBar`'s theme is applied differently, which always override.

**app_bar_theme.dart**

```dart
/// Overrides the default value of [AppBar.titleTextStyle]
/// property in all descendant [AppBar] widgets.
///
/// If this property is specified, then [backwardsCompatibility]
/// should be false (the default).
///
/// See also:
///
///  * [toolbarTextStyle], which overrides the default of [AppBar.toolbarTextStyle]
///    in all descendant [AppBar] widgets.
final TextStyle? titleTextStyle;
```